# Why Was sentry DNS secret deprecated?

Tags: generics, sentry

I was asking myself why was sentry DNS secret deprecated after versions 9.0?

Does having the DNS secret still working on an Android app pose some security risks?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean DSN, right? not really https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/overview/#parsing-the-dsn

but we recommend migrating to the new one as we'll be deprecating the parsing of the DSN secret at some point.